# ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener don't call when the keyboard appears

Tags: android, kotlin

ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener don't call when the keyboard appears,on api 29

```
private fun setUiWindowInsets() {
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.root) { _, insets ->
            prevPosition = (binding.rvComments.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition()
            binding.container.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
                currentBottomMargin = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom
                updateMargins(
                    bottom = currentBottomMargin
                )
                binding.rvComments.scrollToPosition(prevPosition)
            }
            insets
        }
    }
```

I try use  WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

I call this function in OnViewCreated.My root element is constraint.

Comment: can you be more descriptive please

Comment: @ÖmerSeyfettinYavuzyiğit add description

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was setting the listener on the decorView of the window as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76163728/1441731